# order a list of data frames in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list securities like

```
securities <- c("ds", "as", "sad", "dsf", "sdf")
```

I have another list of data frames, with names(d) same but in different order than securities, like

```
 d <- c("as" = df1 , "sad" = df2 , "sdf" = df3 , "dsf" = df4 , "ds" = df5)
where df1,...df5 are some data frames
```

What's the code that would arrange the list d so that the names in d are of the same order as securities.

Comment: `d = d[securities]`

Comment: Also while adding to a list of  d["name"] =  df (df is a data frame), I get the error,  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. Whats the possible solution here

Comment: When assigning a **single item** to a `list`, you need to use `[[`, `d[["name"]] = df`. I'd highly recommend reading the FAQ on the [difference between `[` and `[[`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/903061)